# Help with UV Mapping Islands

Tags: uv

I'm trying to export a Mercy UV Texture (for use in Tabletop Simulator :P) but I've been struggling a bit. As you can see here, the textures are positioned / look like they are working correctly before I begin the UV unwrap, however after unwrapping the texture begins to act a bit weird.

[image: Model Joined, texture still appears fine]

It seems that the UV Map is just overlaying one of the textures on top of the whole map, rather than assigning each texture to each island (I'm sorry if my terminology isn't quite right), as shown here.

[image: Smart Unwrapped, texture distored]

So my question is how do I properly assign textures to each part of the UV map? I read online somewhere that placing each texture into the correct island manually is an option, however given the hundreds of islands this isn't practicable at all for me. Considering that the model and textures look fine before UV Mapping, I'm assuming that there is a much easier way to do this, and that I am missing a setting somewhere?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you need to make sure you have the correct uv map selected under the vertex properties ( right panel )

Comment: I am really sorry but I am unsure what you mean, is this something I have to do before or after using the Smart Unwrap function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Why are you uv mapping, when it's already unwrapped?

Comment: I want to create a texture file of the complete model, which will be used by the game Tabletop Simulator since it reads the geometry and textures separately (I have no idea how this is done for any other games / software etc). 


I am starting with the model I posted in the first picture, with the character textured correctly. I want to get the all textures and islands into a single jpg so that when the game reads the geometry and jpg together the object will appear in game textured properly - sorry if my terminology is all messed up - I thought this process was called UV mapping

Comment: It's a bit cryptic. So to be clear you want to create a custom texture for the model, right? Or you want to pack multiple uv maps into one?  What is causing the uv map to go broke?

Comment: I want to pack multiple UV maps into one, since after joining all the parts of the model together the UVs were all overlapping one another. I followed instructions elsewhere which told me to use the  Smart UV Project tool to fix the overlapping UVs but once I do this I get the result shown in image 2

Comment: What does the UV map look like when you click on the character and go into edit mode?

Comment: Many of the UVs are overlapping one another, as shown here

https://ibb.co/iYV9zo

Comment: You model is already unwrapped (the fact that the textures look good is a dead giveaway) if you blindly re unwrap it you will naturally break the current correct layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, I have several texture materials. I'll convert everything just to a single texture.
[image]

First you will have to create a new 'UV Map'.

Now enter edit mode. See how my mesh is blurred and overlapping, just like yours.
[image]

With the new 'UV Map' selected, unfold the mesh using 'Smart UV Project'
[image]

Now in UV image editing mode, create a new texture where you will receive all textures. Opt for a resolution of 2048 or higher for better texture quality.

Now go to Scene> Bake> Bake mode and select 'Textures'
[image]

Click on bake and you will get all the textures of your character in that single image.

Now go to the Materials tab and delete all existing materials there, and create a new material.
[image]

Go to the texture tab and create a new texture and select the image you just created.

Everything is ready. All textures are rendered correctly.
[image]

Note that if any texture has alpha, it will lose transparency and will not have the expected result, as you can see in the hair and mustache.

I hope I have helped you and other people who are looking into this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about the last few steps so this has solved my issue! Thanks to everyone else who chimed in too!

Comment: Glad to have helped!