# Using two or more separate UV maps and textures on the same material and model

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

I joined two meshes together and now need to add a texture to them. The entire unwrapped mesh is currently on the head's texture: (right)
[image]

You can make out the body's unwrapped mesh above the head's unwrapped mesh. I would like to move the body's unwrapped mesh away from the head's onto another texture.

How do I separate the head's and body's unwrapped meshes onto separate textures, all in the same material? (If they can be disconnected onto seperate textures, but with two materials as well, I'm fine with that but prefer the same material).

EDIT:
To be more clear, I basically want to keep the current unwrap (yes, overlapping) and move the top unwrap (the body's) onto a different texture and keep the heads unwrap on this current texture without interference from the body's unwrap.

Comment: why do you want only one material? don't you want to create a new one for the body? anyway, it looks like you can merge different textures into one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57944/bake-taxtures-to-one-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to unfold your entire mesh and separate one area for the head and one for the body. There can be no overlapping meshes.
[image]

Now save the 'UV layout' to do the texturing.
[image]

What I did was like that, half I used for the head, and half for the body. The rest is transparent not to overwrite one image in the other at the time of placing in the blender.

Head
[image]

Body
[image]

Now just put them in the blender and that's it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work in Blender with the overlapping meshes? That's what I was trying to get, overlapping meshes, two textures/UV maps.

Comment: Two textures for overlapping meshes are not possible in a single material because one texture overlaps the other. You can use different materials for each texture, or unfold the entire mesh and do it all in a single texture. You can get more information about this in this topic
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111691/help-with-uv-mapping-islands

Comment: So basically no. Thanks, I may use that in the future but in my case, I just made an extra large image to fit the other UV mesh.